# How to map a simple ArrayList to a VO using Dozer

Tags: java, dozer

I'm using Dozer to convert my objects. But I've a problem to map a simple List...
I retrieve a `ResultSet` from `Hibernate` as an `Object List` and I want to map it to my complex type object.

So, my source is like :

```
List < Object > list = new ArrayList< Object > ();
list.add("Name");
list.add("Address");
```

And my Value Object is :

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public String name; 
    public String address; 
}
```

I just want to map `list[0]` ==> `MyClass.name` and `list[1]` ==> `MyClass.address` properties but I don't find how...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Dozer **does Not** support this (the ideal situation):

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>MyClass</class-a>
    <class-b>java.util.List</class-b>       
    <field>          
        <a is-accessible="true">name</a>
        <b>this[0]</b>
    </field>        
</mapping>
```

It would only map to `name` the whole string representation of the `List`, so your `name` property would end up with the value *[Name, Address]*.

Your best option would be to put your `List` in a **holder** class and map it like this:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>MyClass</class-a>
    <class-b>MyHolder</class-b>     
    <field>          
        <a is-accessible="true">name</a>
        <b>holded[0]</b>
    </field>
    <field>          
        <a is-accessible="true">address</a>
        <b>holded[1]</b>
    </field>    
</mapping>
```

`MyHolder` class just contains your `List` instance in the `holded` field and provide access to it with a getter method.

In the field mappings `is-accessible="true"` is required because `MyClass` properties are `public` and have no accessors. I recommend you to make those properties `private` and create accessor methods.

Comment: Ok, I also tried to use your first solution but without success :(. As you say, the property was filled by the value [Name, Address]. For your last solution, I think it's not sexy... I don't like to wrap uselessly an object, but I'm ok with you, it is the best option ! To finish, of course, in this example, the properties name & address are public, but it is only for the example :). Thanks to you. For information, I decided to use a Map instead of the List, which is easy to use with the "this" notation.